# Jquery traversal not working with .closest(), .parent().parent() etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, traversal

I have an annoying problem whereby I can only get the top two parents of an element and it will not go beyond that. .closest() does not work either. When I look at the hierachy it should work according to the specifications outlined in the documentation.

Here is what I have:

```
<div id="telephonezone" class="bbox">
<table id="phones" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr><th width="70">Type</th><th>Phone number</th><th width="30"></th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody><tr style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">
<td class="primaryset">N/A</td>
<td class="primaryset">0208 989 8183</td>
<td class="primaryset">
    <img data-id="0" data-dbid="1126" src="images/dandy-color/cancel.png" title="Delete."></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

My Jquery:

```
$('.bbox tr td img').live('click', function(){
id = $(this).attr('data-dbid') ;
cont = $(this).parent().parent().html() ;
alert(cont);
})
```

cont = $(this).parent().parent().html() ; gets me the contents of the < tr >, but if I try going higher than that I just get undefined. Same results with prevAll, prev, closest or any combination of them.

How do I select the ID of the div at line one when I click on that image inside the td?

---

```
  html += '><img data-id="'+i+'" data-dbid="'+v[4]+'" src="images/dandy-color/cancel.png" title="Delete." /></td>' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying that you want the first div parent found in all ancestors.

```
$(this).parents("div:first").attr("id");
```

Comment: Unfortunately it had no effect, I still get undefined :(

Comment: @imperium2335 - made a change, try parents()

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to access deleted element parents. That's why traversal not working.

```
<a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('tr').remove(); console.log('this should be null:' + $(this).closest('div'))">
```

In this example you can not access 'tr's parents since you have removed it from page.